# Bash: Why a negative substring expression error exits a function but not the whole script?

Tags: arrays, bash, error-handling

Why, when a negative substring expression error is raised, Bash exits from a function, but not from the whole script, even if `errexit` is set?

Sample:

```bash
function foo { echo "${@:0:-1}"; echo skipped_here; }

set -o errexit
foo "$@"
echo reaches_here
```

This will output:

```
/path/to/script: line 1: -1: substring expression < 0
reaches_here
```

If I replace `echo "${@:0:-1}"` with `false`, the script exits immediately.

Comment: Good Name. Also, you probably want to *unset* errexit, not set it, because otherwise exiting on error is exactly the specified behavior

Comment: Looks like a bug. Consider reporting it

Comment: I can't get the error message `/path/to/script: line 1: -1: substring expression < 0`. What bash version do you use?

Comment: Useful reading: [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: @Fravadona Version `5.1.16(1)-release`